# php not redirecting and logging in

Tags: php, jquery, security, authentication, pjax

So when i log in with correct details my system gives an error message with a blank message and does not redirect? Why is this happening, i don't see how returning a blank error is possible in my code?

calling it:

```
$("#log").click(function () {
    username = $("#user").val();
    password = $("#password").val();
    submit = $("#log").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: "submit=" + submit + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                //should never be called?
            } else {
                $("#error-log").remove();
                var error_msg = response;
                $("#s-log").append('<div id="error-log" class="err welcome dismissible">' + error_msg + '</div>');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

checking:

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('FRCteam3482Remember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
            header("Location: workspace/index.php");
            echo 'success';
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if(count($err)) {
        $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        // Save the error messages in the session

        echo $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'];
        //php unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
        //header("Location: index.php");
    }
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Location: workspace/index.php");
```

An Ajax request passes data to another page (a script) which processes this data and usually returns some data. You should just echo the data that needs to be returned, not attempt a re-location. The page making the Ajax request should re-direct the current page if necessary, using JavaScript.

Also, you echo data after the header() call, so this echo'd data is probably not sent.

Comment: I want to change pages from the login/register page (current) to the actual members area?

Comment: @user1361852 Then why are you using ajax?

Comment: To update/show the error messages and show/hide the registration form.

Comment: @user1361852 You can't redirect the page in an ajax response.  Since you've resigned to using javascript, just use javascript to conduct the redirect.

Comment: how could i do that without using the absolute address, is there a way to do it by adding on to the current page's address?

Comment: `window.location` supports relative addresses.

Answer (score 0):

1. On success function **location.reload()**, will reload the current page.
2. another option post url string you want to redirect and after succes do the redirect using the var.

```js
$("#log").click(function(){
    username=$("#user").val();
    password=$("#password").val();
    submit=$("#log").val();
    currentpage=$("#currentpage").val();//submit current page url or some useful info about it
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: "submit="+submit+"&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&currentpage="+currentpage,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.msg=='success') {
                window.location.href=response.url;
            }
            else {
                $("#error-log").remove();
                var error_msg = response;
                $("#s-log").append('<div id="error-log" class="err welcome dismissible">'+error_msg+'</div>');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('FRCteam3482Remember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
            header("Location: workspace/index.php");
            echo "{'msg':'success','url':'".$_POST['currenturl']."'}";
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if(count($err)) {
        $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        // Save the error messages in the session

        echo $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'];
        //php unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
        //header("Location: index.php");
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: how could i use something like `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";` but only by adding onto the current address. So if i ever change domains or something it would still work with having to update it.

Comment: I not sure if I understood your comment, but if i undertood you can put PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in a html element and use it in your Ajax function